How do you know which device tokens are no longer in use for APNs?
I am implementing iOS Push Notifications with APNs using AWS SNS (although not strictly relevant).  When a user enables push notifications, the device token is stored in a database.
Suppose the user has the app installed on more than one device (e.g. an iPad and an iPhone) and they uninstall the app on their iPhone, then re-install it.  From my understanding, a new device token is issued.  How do I know which is the old/unused device token for the iPhone (so I can delete it from my database)?

You need to look for the 410 response when you attempt to send the push and update your database accordingly

You can subscribe a SNS topic to receive mobile app events. In the case where a user has uninstalled the app, SNS would no longer able to send push notifications to that endpoint, which will result in an EventDeliveryFailure event when you next try to send a notification. Using this information, you could delete the endpoint from your database. Optionally, you could also remove any SNS subscriptions pointing to that endpoint as well as delete the endpoint itself from your platform application.
